# Issue with using newline in awk

Tags: memory, awk, newline

I am trying to get a output in csv on my Linux (Centos) box with following columns:

```
"timestamp" "date" "process name" "process id" "%memory"
```

Below is my code:

```
tdydate=$(date +'%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S')
ip=$(ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk 'NR==1 {print $NF}')

echo $tdydate "," $ip "," $(top -b -n 1 | awk 'BEGIN {RS = "\n"} NR>7 {print $12,$1,$10}') > procinfo.csv
```

However, as expected, it doesnt print the info in newline. While, when I just do below it works absolutely fine and prints all required info in desired format:-

```
top -b -n 1 | awk 'BEGIN {RS = "\n"} NR>7 {print $12,$1,$10}' > procinfo.csv
```

When I try to print timestamp and ip as well with echo, the format changes into single line. Can someone please correct me where I am wrong?

Desired output should be in below format:-

First column is timestamp, second is ip, thrid is process name, fourth is process id and fifth one is %memory. It should be comma separated values ( a csv as output).

Comment: Quote the entire string to `echo`. If you leave variables unquoted then the shell eats whitespace.

Comment: Hi, this didnt worked. Did you mean this:- echo "$tdydate "," $ip "," $(top -b -n 1 | awk 'BEGIN {RS = "\n"} NR>7 {print $12,$1,$10}')" > procinfo.csv

Comment: Does that top/awk output create multiple lines? Then you can't do that with one `echo`. Instead stick the first two static fields in the `awk` print `awk -v date="$tdydate" -v ip="$ip" '....{print date","ip","$12,$1,$10}'`

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong here. The desired output isn't clear at all. I can only see one line, with no commas separating any of the data. Please edit your question showing an exact example of your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Your echo statement should be this:

```
echo "$tdydate , $ip , $(top -b -n 1 | awk 'NR>7 {print $12,$1,$10}')" > procinfo.csv
```

As well as wrapping the entire thing in double quotes to preserve white space, I have removed the assignment to `RS`. I don't think that this should be necessary as the default value is a newline on your platform.

Comment: Hi, This unfortunately didnt worked. It gave below as output in CSV:- 11/26/2014 20:29  192.168.0.38   top 1681105 0.0
init 1 0.0  
kthreadd 2 0.0  
migration/0 3 0.0  
ksoftirqd/0 4 0.0  
migration/0 5 0.0  
watchdog/0 6 0.0  
migration/1 7 0.0  
migration/1 8 0.0

Comment: It's not clear from your comment how that output is formatted, nor is it clear from your question what the desired output format is. Please edit your question to show how you would like the output to look.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I have added desired output format to my question. Please advise.. Thanks.